# How to resolve problem to Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.CSharpScript

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, eval

```
[HttpGet("vulnerability")]
public IActionResult vulnerability(string input)
{
  object content = 0;
  try
  {
    content = new Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.CSharpScript(input).EvaluateAsync().Result;
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    content = "";
  }
  return View("Example", new { vuln = content });
}
```

I'm going to implement a "code injection" vulnerability in .net core.

The vulnerable configuration takes input to input and tries to execute it as an eval.
Yes)
Input: 1+1
Result screen: 2

by the way

> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.CSharpScript(input).EvaluateAsync().Result;
>
> An error occurs in the portion. Occurrence Error - CS0712
>
> EvaluateAsync()
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.CSharpScript(input).EvaluateAsync().Result;
>
> An error occurs in the portion. CS0712
>
> EvaluateAsync() Occurrence Error - CS1501

How can I solve this?

I tried to solve the problem by referring to the official document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should like below:

```
    [HttpGet("vulnerability")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> vulnerability(string input)
    {
        object content = 0;
        try
        {
            content =  await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(input);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            content = "";
        }
        return Ok(new { vuln = content });
    }
```

**And the test result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks to you, I solved it :)

but I have one more problem.

        public async Task<IActionResult> Ex2Secure(string input)
        {
            object content = 0;
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d+$"))
            {
                content = "Not Number!";
            }
            else
            . . . . .

Data was transmitted to the view using @ViewData. However, "Not number!" is output when input 1+1 is entered.

How can I solve this?